# Algebra generators of Clifford Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras

A Clifford Algebra $C_k$ is a Real Algebra of dimension $2^k$ with its algebra generators being $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$, satisfying the following relations:
$$
e_i^2 = -1 ~~\& ~~e_je_i = -e_ie_j ~~\text{if} ~~i \neq j. 
$$
The vector space basis of $C_k$ is $\{e_{i_1}\cdots e_{i_r} : i_1 < i_2 \ldots < i_r, ~0 \le r \le k\}$

Let $R^k$ denote the k-space in $C_k$ spanned by $e_1,\ldots,e_k$. Now let $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}$ be some other basis of $R^k$. Then my question is following:

*Do we still have the following relations?*

$$
u_i^2 = -1 ~~\& ~~u_ju_i = -u_iu_j ~~\text{if} ~~i \neq j. 
$$

If no, then under the restriction of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ being an orthonormal basis, do we have the above-mentioned relations on $ u_i$s?

---

What I have tried is given below:

Let $u_i = \sum_l a_l e_l$ and $u_j = \sum_n b_n e_n$. Then we have
$$
u_i u_j = \sum_i^k a_ib_i e_i^2 + \sum_{~m,n \\ m \neq n} a_m b_n e_me_n 
$$
$$
\& 
$$
$$
u_j u_i 
= \sum_i^k b_ia_i e_i^2 + \sum_{~n,m \\ m \neq n} b_n a_m e_ne_m 
= \sum_i^k a_ib_i e_i^2 + (-1)\sum_{~n,m \\ m \neq n} b_n a_m e_me_n 
$$
From here I cannot establish the fact $u_ju_i = - u_iu_j$

Comment: No, we don't have those relations in general, and yes, we still have them if the $u_i$ are an orthonormal basis. There is a different definition of the Clifford algebra in terms of the inner product that makes this clearer, which you can find on Wikipedia.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you please help me understand why for orthonormal basis we have the relations?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}$

Given any $K$-vector space $V$ with quadratic form $Q$, we may define the associated Clifford algebra  $\Cl(V,Q)$. Canonically identifying $K$ and $V$ as subsets of $\Cl(V,Q)$, its fundamental property is that $v^2 = Q(v)$ for all $v \in V$. By definition, $Q$ has an associated symmetric bilinear form $B$, where when the characteristic of $K$ is not 2 we have
$$
  B(v,w) = \frac12(Q(v+w) - Q(v) - Q(w)) = \frac12((v+w)^2 - v^2 - w^2) = \frac12(vw + wv)
$$
for $v,w \in V$. It follows that if $B(v,w) = 0$, i.e. $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal, then
$$
  0 = vw + wv \implies vw = -wv,
$$
and it is clear that $v$ and $w$ anticommute iff they are orthogonal. This is still all true when the characteristic of $K$ is 2, but we instead have to define $B$ by
$$
  B(v,w) = Q(v+w) - Q(v) - Q(w).
$$

For more on defining Clifford algebras, see chapter 14 of *Clifford Algebras and Spinors* (2001) by Pertti Lounesto.